# Ionic click event to open an accordion requires double click on the icon

Tags: ionic-framework, accordion

I have started working on ionic a couple of months ago and i am finding it real difficult to implement an Accordion list.

I want to open the subcategories when the main category is clicked.i want to do it in a single click but it requires double click to open the list.

this is my html:

```
<div *ngFor="let d of SubCategories">
<div class="accordion" (click)="abcd(d)">   //Here is click I assigned to open the sublist
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{d.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [ngModel]="pepperoni"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</div>

<div class="panel">
<ion-item *ngFor="let e of SubCategories1"> 
    <ion-label>{{e.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [ngModel]="pepperoni"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
</div>
</div>
```

my typescript file:

```
abcd(data){
    console.log(data.id);
    this.abcde = data.id;
    this.CatAndSubCat1();
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {        //this assigns a click again which opens the list after than.so the sub list opens after 2 clicks
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to Open the sublist in a single click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's an open issue with Ionic framework itself and there are fixes available but not sure whether it will fix your problem or not. Let's give a try.

1. Add (tap) instead of (click) or
2. Add the below class in you SCSS file

   .input-cover { display: none; }

Comment: doesn't open up the child, but changes the state of the parent